# Are PlaybackSettings persistent between tests?

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

If I modify a playback setting inside a test method, for example:

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyTest()
{
    Playback.PlaybackSettings.AlwaysSearchControls = true;
}
```

would that setting persists between my tests? Or would it be reset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of a Unit Test is that any given one can be run independently. Thus, state and order are not guaranteed and should not be relied on. Breakpointing constructors will show you that your test class is even instantiated once per test.

EDIT: Note that "a single test" refers to a single `[TestMethod]`

Though static fields remain persistent, this is against usual Unit Test practices. Instead, if every one of your tests relies on that filed being set, use a `[TestInitialize]` marked method, as it will be run before each and every one of your tests, even when running multiple ones at once.

Short answer for all of this is that yes, it might persist, but both standards and safety demand that you *assume* it doesn't.

Comment: so the short answer is that it does persist?

Comment: The short answer is that it might persist, but standards and saftey demand that you assume it doesn't. I've incorporated such into my original answer.

Comment: My situation is reverse: I'm assuming that it does not persist, but because I cannot be sure of that, I have to clean it up after each test. If I know for sure that it does not persist, then I don't have to waste time doing the clean up.

Answer (score 0):

The previously accepted answer isn't very precise, and not specific to Coded UI tests, so I decided to add a more precise answer.

The PlaybackSettings specifically do not persist between tests.

In fact, I tested the behavior to make sure by running these two tests in a single test run:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void test1()
    {
        Assert.IsFalse(Playback.PlaybackSettings.AlwaysSearchControls);
        Playback.PlaybackSettings.AlwaysSearchControls = true;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void test2()
    {
        Assert.IsFalse(Playback.PlaybackSettings.AlwaysSearchControls);
        Playback.PlaybackSettings.AlwaysSearchControls = true;
    }
```

Both tests passed. :)